# Installing python dev libraries and headers via setup.py

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I have a python package that requires the python development libraries and headers to be installed. Is there any way to easily install these in `setup.py install` and `pip install`?

The closest thing I have come up with so far is to either just tell users to install them manually, individually do apt, yum, etc installs in setup.py, or manually download and build the python libs, which would still likely require specialization depending on OS.